# Dash Datatable: Inherit height from parent div

Tags: plotly-dash

I have a standard design with some controls and a datatable below. I would like the datatable to adjust to the window height. My first thought was to include the table in a div and assign a % height to the div.

However, it seems that the table only responds to vh and not %. Currently I am setting the table height via f"calc(100vh - {margin*2+controls}px)".

Is there any way to adjust the height of the table in proportion to the div it is contained in? Or is there generally a preferred way to achieve this behaviour?